# Jquery datatable vertical scroll hides header of HTML table

Tags: jquery, datatables

My table thead disappears when I enable scrolling over my datatable.

This is the **HTML** of my table:

```
<table id="tblProviders">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Jquery **Datatable**:

```
$(#tblProviders).dataTable({
    "scrollY": 300,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "pageLength": pageCount,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "paging": false,
    data: array,
    columns: [{
    "data": "Name"
    }, 
    {
    "data": "Time"
    }
    }]
});
```

Without the `scrollY` option it works perfectly fine. Why does it hide my `th`?

Comment: Have you tried the fixed header plug-in? https://github.com/DataTables/FixedHeader

Answer (score 0):

can you please check , by putting a css style to the thead as style="position:fixed;"

Comment: Yes I did, still issue persist

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

did u try "fixedHeader: true" option in your datatable?

```
$(#tblProviders).dataTable({
   "fixedHeader": true,
   "scrollY": 300,
   "autoWidth": false,
   "pageLength": pageCount,
   "bDestroy": true,
   "paging": false,
   data: array,
   columns: [{
    "data": "Name"
   }, 
   {
    "data": "Time"
   }
 }]
});
```

Comment: Yes I did, still issue persist

Comment: This is assuming the OP is using the fixed header plug-in

Comment: @DarrenSweeney for `fixedHeader` option to work do I need to install a separate plugin?

Comment: @HumaAli Yes, as far as I know

Comment: `FixedHeader is not currently compatible with tables that have the scrolling features of DataTables enabled`. According to https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/